# Nova services scheduler and conductor couldn't start after server reboot

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, keystone

I have installed allinone setup using packstack in a server. I have generated one windows server instance and it was working fine. The system was left idle and later it was rebooted. After reboot, I'm not able to see the keystone service. I'm not able to start keystone service as well. It says the unit is not found but earlier keystone service was working fine and there are no logs of keystone after reboot. I'm not able ot start nova-conductor and nova-scheduler services. I'm attaching the log files for reference. Can anyone please share a way ahead to eliminate the error.

Thanks in advance.

****Nova-scheduler Log:****

2021-12-28 14:02:36.568 44587 ERROR nova keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5f470529e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 14:02:36.568 44587 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.790 44597 INFO oslo_service.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _discover_hosts_in_cells because its interval is negative
2021-12-28 14:02:38.799 44597 WARNING keystoneauth.identity.generic.base [-] Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.: keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f53f3575a20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 CRITICAL nova [-] Unhandled error: keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f53f358e9e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     raise err
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     sock.connect(sa)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 253, in connect
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     socket_checkerr(fd)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 51, in socket_checkerr
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     raise socket.error(err, errno.errorcode[err])
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     chunked=chunked)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self.send(msg)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self.connect()
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     conn = self._new_conn()
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f53f358e9e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     timeout=timeout
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f53f358e9e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1004, in _send_request
2021-12-28 14:02:38.803 44597 ERROR nova     resp = self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)

**Nova-Conductor Log**

2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     chunked=chunked)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.send(msg)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.connect()
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     conn = self._new_conn()
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc0e5be6978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     timeout=timeout
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc0e5be6978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1004, in _send_request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     resp = self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc0e5be6978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/bin/nova-conductor", line 10, in 
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     sys.exit(main())
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/cmd/conductor.py", line 44, in main
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     topic=rpcapi.RPC_TOPIC)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/service.py", line 270, in create
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     periodic_interval_max=periodic_interval_max)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/service.py", line 128, in **init**
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.manager = manager_class(host=self.host, *args, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 121, in **init**
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.compute_task_mgr = ComputeTaskManager()
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 247, in **init**
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.report_client = report.SchedulerReportClient()
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/scheduler/client/report.py", line 186, in **init**
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self._client = self._create_client()
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/scheduler/client/report.py", line 229, in _create_client
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     client = self._adapter or utils.get_sdk_adapter('placement')
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/utils.py", line 1079, in get_sdk_adapter
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     return getattr(conn, service_type)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/service_description.py", line 93, in **get**
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     endpoint = proxy_mod.Proxy.get_endpoint(proxy)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 282, in get_endpoint
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     return self.session.get_endpoint(auth or self.auth, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1225, in get_endpoint
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     return auth.get_endpoint(self, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 380, in get_endpoint
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     allow_version_hack=allow_version_hack, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 271, in get_endpoint_data
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     service_catalog = self.get_access(session).service_catalog
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 134, in get_access
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 208, in get_auth_ref
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 184, in get_auth_ref
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     authenticated=False, log=False, **rkwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1131, in post
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 913, in request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     resp = send(**kwargs)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1020, in _send_request
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova     raise exceptions.ConnectFailure(msg)
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.26.6.238', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc0e5be6978>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED',))
2021-12-28 15:08:32.128 82721 ERROR nova

Answer (score 0):

The error messages in the logfile say that it cannot connect to `http://172.26.6.238:5000/v3/auth/tokens`.  That will be your Keystone service.

You need to investigate why your Keystone service is not listening for connections.

> I'm not able to start Keystone service as well.

Solve that problem first.

> It says the unit is not found ...

Suspicious!  `Systemd` unit files don't just spontaneously disappear.  You need to figure out where they have gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Stephen for your valuable reply. I will resolve the keystone issue.